# Select random values from a column without replacement multiple times

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet with data in column A. I have a list of dates in column B. There are more dates in column B than there are values in column A. Column C is empty:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Date 1 |  |
| Value 2 | Date 2 |  |
| Value 3 | Date 3 |  |
|  | Date 4 |  |
|  | Date 5 |  |
|  | Date 6 |  |
|  | Date 7 |  |
|  | Date 8 |  |

I want to select a random value from column A for every date in column B without immediate replacement. Replacement will have to happen after all values have been used, so I want to start the random selection fresh once this happens. So a valid solution would look like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Date 1 | Value 2 |
| Value 2 | Date 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 3 | Date 3 | Value 1 |
|  | Date 4 | Value 3 |
|  | Date 5 | Value 1 |
|  | Date 6 | Value 2 |
|  | Date 7 | Value 2 |
|  | Date 8 | Value 3 |

Dates 1-3 get a random selection of the 3 values in column A, then 4-6 get another, etc. Note that Value 2 occurs on date 6 and date 7 because selection starts again; this is fine.

I would also like to be able to add values to column A later on. I would like the random selection to update for any date after the date I make the update on (using the wallclock or something to determine the date) while keeping the values in column C for days that have passed (including the day the update is made). So if I add Value 4 to column A on date 5, a valid solution would look like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Date 1 | Value 2 |
| Value 2 | Date 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 3 | Date 3 | Value 1 |
| Value 4 | Date 4 | Value 3 |
|  | Date 5 | Value 1 |
|  | Date 6 | Value 4 |
|  | Date 7 | Value 2 |
|  | Date 8 | Value 3 |
|  | Date 9 | Value 2 |
|  | Date 10 | Value 1 |
|  | Date 11 | Value 4 |
|  | Date 12 | Value 1 |
|  | Date 13 | Value 2 |

The values in column C for dates 1-5 are left unchanged. The values for dates 6 and 7 are recomputed, selected randomly from (value 2, value 4) because they have not been selected since the random selection "reset" after day 3. All 4 values are randomly selected in days 8-11, then "reset" again after day 11.

I tried

```
=array_constrain(sort(filter(A1:A,A1:A<>""),randarray(counta(A1:A),1),1),5,1)
```

to select 5 days of values from column A without replacement. However, this only selected 3 values because column A only had 3 values.

Comment: It's difficult to see how you would do the second part of your question without either manually adding more formulas or using a script.

Comment: @TomSharpe Makes sense, thanks. Any suggestions on how to do it using a script?

Comment: I think it might be possible to achieve what you've requested in the second part of your question (retain previous results in column C whilst changing all future-dated ones) using a single formula without scripting, however it would involve you enabling iterative calculations (aka circular referencing) in the sheet - would you be open to this?

Comment: @TheGodofBiscuits Sure, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: In answer to your question about a script, I think it would boil down to writing a function that adds a new random number to a partly-filled array of random numbers. Various ways you could do this in code, one of them being repeatedly generating a random number until you got one that hadn't been used before. Then a look-up to map the random numbers to value 1, value 2 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a formula you can use which I think gets closer to what you want. With your table at the top left of the sheet, enable iterative calculation in Settings, set the maximum number of iterations to 1 and set the recalculation interval to 'On change and every hour'. Then place the following in C2:

```
=arrayformula(let(
values,tocol(A2:A,1),
dates,tocol(B2:B,1),
valcount,counta(values),
datecount,counta(dates),
groupcount,ceiling(datecount/valcount),
paddates,wrapcols(dates,valcount*groupcount,),
randomindexes,tocol(byrow(randarray(groupcount,valcount),lambda(row,rank(row,row)))),
selection,xlookup(filter(randomindexes,len(paddates)),sequence(valcount),values),
if(dates>today(),selection,C2:C)))
```

I am assuming that the dates in column B are genuine dates and are formatted as such, and that you will 'initialise' the table with a series of dates in column B which start from the day after the day you set the table up. Column C will be populated with a random selection from the values in column A (without replacement), looping after all values have been selected, and the with each new day the previous day's value selected is 'memorised' by exploiting a deliberate circular reference.

If you change the number of values in column A during the time the table is running, future days will randomly select from the new list of values without affecting the previous day's selections; the one thing I haven't been able to implement is where you've asked for the random selection immediately after a change in the number of values to take into account the previous values randomly selected and not to pick those - I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks so much! Works great, not a problem on the recalculation part. 
One more extension: same setup with a set of values in column A and dates in column B, but now there are multiple columns to fill with values, say C, D, E, and F. Could you extend the formula to place random values in each of the four columns then start again once they've all been used once? Again, all values should occur in one of the columns before repeats happen, and when repeats start, the same value can't occur in multiple columns in a single row.

Comment: Glad it was of use to you. Re. the new ask it's almost certainly doable, but please post it as a new question (along with example tables for the input and output again) and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513736

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=BYROW(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,BYROW(B2:B, LAMBDA(rg, RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A2:A)))))),COUNTA(B2:B),1), LAMBDA(r, INDEX(QUERY({""&A2:A}, "Where Col1 <> '' "), r, 1)))
```

[image]

The formula works as follows:

1. The ArrayFormula function is used to apply the IF function to each value in column B. The IF function checks if the value in column B is empty. If it is empty, the IF function returns the result of the RANDBETWEEN function. If the value in column B is not empty, the IF function returns the value in column B.
2. The BYROW function is used to apply the LAMBDA function to each row of the result of the ArrayFormula function. The LAMBDA function creates a custom function that takes a row as input and returns a random value from column A, constrained by the number of values in column B.
3. The ARRAY_CONSTRAIN function is used to constrain the result of the BYROW function to the number of values in column B.
4. The BYROW function is used to apply the INDEX function to each row of the result of the ARRAY_CONSTRAIN function. The INDEX function returns the value of the cell at the specified row and column within the range {"&A2:A}. This range is filtered to only include non-empty values.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't work based on your gif. It's supposed to select all n values in column A without replacement in the first n days, then all n values in column A in days n+1 to 2n, etc. It also doesn't address the second part of my question about adding values on a later date without affecting previous values.