# Select random values from a column without replacement multiple times and place into multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Similar to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164625/), I have a Google Sheet with data in column A. I have a list of dates in column B. There can be more dates in column B than there are values in column A. I have N empty columns. In this example, N=4:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Date 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Value 2 | Date 2 |  |  |  |  |
| Value 3 | Date 3 |  |  |  |  |
| Value 4 | Date 4 |  |  |  |  |
| Value 5 | Date 5 |  |  |  |  |
| Value 6 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 7 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 9 |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to select N random values from column A for every date in column B without immediate replacement. Replacement will have to happen after all values have been used, so I want to start the random selection fresh once this happens. So a valid solution would look like:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value 1 | Date 1 | Value 4 | Value 3 | Value 1 | Value 8 |
| Value 2 | Date 2 | Value 7 | Value 5 | Value 9 | Value 2 |
| Value 3 | Date 3 | Value 6 | Value 2 | Value 1 | Value 7 |
| Value 4 | Date 4 | Value 5 | Value 3 | Value 6 | Value 9 |
| Value 5 | Date 5 | Value 4 | Value 8 | Value 5 | Value 1 |
| Value 6 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 7 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 8 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Value 9 |  |  |  |  |  |

In columns C - F, dates 1-2 get a random selection of the 9 values in column A. C3 gets the last of the 9 values. The remainder of row 3, all of row 4, and C5 & D5 contain a random selection of the 9 unique values. Importantly, each row does not contain any repeats. However, values 2 and 7 occur in subsequent rows (2 and 3).

I would also like to be able to add values to column A later on. I would like the random selection to update for any date after the date I make the update on (using the wallclock or something to determine the date) while keeping the values in columns C-F for days that have passed (including the day the update is made).

I tried the solution for the linked issue. However, it only outputs values in one column, not N.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution

`=LET(vals,A2:A10,dates,B2:B6,empty_cols,4,slots,empty_cols*ROWS(dates),WRAPROWS(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(slots/ROWS(vals))),LAMBDA(a,_,VSTACK(a,SORT(vals,RANDARRAY(ROWS(vals)),)))),slots,1),empty_cols))`

With open ranges

`=LET(vals,A2:A,dates,B2:B,empty_cols,4,slots,empty_cols*COUNTA(dates),WRAPROWS(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(slots/COUNTA(vals))),LAMBDA(a,_,VSTACK(a,SORT(TOCOL(vals,1) ,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(vals)),)))),slots,1),empty_cols))`

Comment: Thanks, but I tested it and it doesn't keep the same value from occurring multiple times in a single row.

Comment: can you share a sheet where you demonstrate the issue?